# Luke 5:17 - the power of the Lord was present for Him to perform healing

Tags: luke, healing

In the NASB, Luke 5:17 says "the power of the Lord was present for Him to perform healing".  I would have thought, and still do, that at least after Jesus's encounter with John that the power of the Lord for healing was always present for Jesus. In Matthew 13:58 it does say that Jesus could only perform few miracles in His hometown because of their lack of faith.  But that sounded more like Jesus's willingness to perform miracles, not a lack of the Lord's power.

The phrase in Luke 5:17 also doesn't sound like it's there to remind readers that Jesus has the Lord's power to perform healing, since the previous sections kind of make that obvious.  Also, in the NASB the word "present" is italicized, indicating that it was not in the original text.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

Is there some hint here that the power of the Lord was only sometimes present for Jesus to call upon.  I have a hard time believing that.

Answer (score 1):

From several verses we get a clear sense of the power and provisions Jesus needed and had reliable access to.

> For I have come down from heaven, not to do My own will, but to do the will of Him who sent Me. John 6:38

Jesus being filled with God's spirit knew the will of God and did accordingly. Clearly he didn't heal all people of all problems because it was not God's will for this to happen.

> And the power of the Lord was with him to heal v17

Sometimes the power went out of him and he seemed unaware of God's specific action like healing the woman who was bleeding, Mark 5:25.

The power was God's. Jesus always expressed where his provision came from - his actions, words, etc all from God (John 12:49, 14:10). To the point that his very life was sustained through many times of great anguish especially as the cross approached.

> During the days of Jesus’ earthly life, he offered up prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the One who could save him from death, and he was heard because of his reverence. Heb 5:7

Jesus and the Father were on the same page, having the same purpose for the same outcome - to accomplish his saving work on the cross. They were never separated, never not connected in the spirit. Jesus always had he power he needed and he had to learn to rely on the Father's timely and sufficient response. This however didn't make Jesus life an easy sheltered journey...

> Although he was a son, **he learned obedience from the things which he suffered**. And having been perfected, he became the source of eternal salvation for all those who obey him Heb 5:8

Answer (score 1):

Luke 5:

> 17b the power of the Lord was present for Him to perform healing

How is it said, the power of the Lord was present with Christ to heal? had not Christ this power of healing at all times?

Matthew Poole answers:

> Doubtless he had, for he was always the Lord that healeth us. The Divine **nature** once united to the human was never separated from Christ, but it did not always put forth itself, being as to that directed by his **will**.

Yes, it is Jesus' nature to heal but only as directed by the Father's will.

> But as the end of Christ’s miracles was for the confirmation of his doctrine; so we shall observe, that mostly after preaching he wrought his miraculous operations.

In this case, the miraculous healing is a sign to confirm Jesus' teaching:

> 22 Jesus knew what they were thinking and asked, “Why are you thinking these things in your hearts? 23Which is easier: to say, ‘Your sins are forgiven,’ or to say, ‘Get up and walk’? 24But I want you to know that **the Son of Man has authority on earth to forgive sins**.” So he said to the paralyzed man, “I tell you, get up, take your mat and go home.” 25Immediately he stood up in front of them, took what he had been lying on and went home praising God. 26Everyone was amazed and gave praise to God. They were filled with awe and said, “We have seen remarkable things today.”

There was another occasion that it was the will of the Father to heal everyone, Luke 6:

> 19
> And all the crowd sought to touch him, for power came out from him and **healed them all**.

Is there some hint here that the power of the Lord was only sometimes present for Jesus to call upon?

No, the power of the Lord was always present for Jesus to call upon. It's just that there were occasions that Jesus chose not to exercise that power, Matthew 26:

> 53 Do you think I cannot call on my Father, and he will at once put at my disposal more than twelve legions of angels? 54But how then would the Scriptures be fulfilled that say it must happen in this way?”